Surface Plot of x,y,z Data with Different z Dimension MATLAB
I have the following data:
M = 1000; % [seconds]
D = 50; % number of masses
t = [0:dt:M];
y = randn(length(t),1); % [unitless] amplitude
z = [1:1:2*D]; % [unitless] number of eigenfrequencies
data = [t,y,z];

I would like to create a surface plot of data where the x-axis is t or time, the y-axis is y or amplitude, and the z-axis is eigenfrequency number. The x and y data both have a dimension of t, but the z-data has a dimension of 2D. Is it possible to plot x,y,z data using z data with a different dimension than the x and y data in MATLAB using surf() or plot3()?
EDIT: This was a poorly formulated question. The idea was to plot x,y,z data using different dimensions, which is simply not possible.

You'll need to establish a relationship between your parameters. For every (t,y) combination you'll need a value for z in order to create a surface. If you do not have a function that defines that relation, f(t,y) = z, you cannot do this. In other words, from a MATLAB perspective, you'll need as much points in z as you have in both t  and y, otherwise you'll error out. Case in point: data cannot be created in your current code, as z has less elements than either t or y. You'll need to find more elements of z to be able to do this.

And if you want a surface, your inputs will have to be matrices. You can convert t and y into matrices easily using meshgrid, but (as above) you'll have to find a value of z at each (t,y) pair.

I think the question is wrongly or incorrectly phrased. Are there any typos in the code or description? What exactly do you want? It's technically possible to do what you asked (using [a,b,c] = meshgrid(t,y,z); figure; plot3(a(:),b(:),c(:),'.'); ) but I'm not sure this is helpful..

The direct answer to your question (Is it possible to plot x,y,z data using z data with a different dimension than the x and y data) would be "No". x, y and z are required to have the same number of components in order to generate a plot. This sounds a bit like an XY-problem. It might be helpful if you explain a bit more what this code is intended to do and why you think the described plot to be a good visual representation of your data.

I don’t understand what your desired output is. How do your z values relate to the (x,y) values? In a surface, you have a specific height (z value) for each combination of (x,y) coordinates. But your data doesn’t, so it doesn’t represent a surface.

This was a poorly formulated question. The idea was to plot x,y,z data using different dimensions, which is simply not possible.

Yes, you can use plot3 to plot it. To solve the length discrepancies, note that you just need to add one element to z to make it the same length with t and y.
dt = 1;
M = 100; % [seconds]
D = 50; % number of masses
t = [0:dt:M];
y = randn(length(t),1); % [unitless] amplitude
z = [1:1:2*D+1]; % [unitless] number of eigenfrequencies

figure
plot3(t,y,z,'LineWidth', 2);
xlabel('t')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z')

Result:

If you change the t and y dimension, you need to update the z dimension accordingly. As I guess from you question, you want z to be something from 1 up to 2*D (two times the number of masses). Let's say you want to change the length of time here to 1000, you can use linspace to choose the correct step size for z.
M = 1000; % [seconds]
D = 50; % number of masses
dt = 1;
t = [0:dt:M];
y = randn(length(t),1); % [unitless] amplitude
%z = [1:1:2*D]; % [unitless] number of eigenfrequencies
z = linspace(1,2*D,length(t));

Result:


M happens to be equal to 2D by pure coincidence. What would you do if M was say 1000? (See edited question)

@Jonathan Frutschy Then you need to change it to the correct dimension, otherwise you can't plot it.

@JonathanFrutschy I updated the answer to your request. Let me know if this is what you want.

Yes this is the best I could ask for (see original post edit)
